# How to set parameters in a batch file equal to a VB6 variable

Tags: batch-file, vb6, vbscript, imagemagick, dos

In my batch file, I am calling a VBScript and passing it 3 parameters. The parameters are "IPADDRESS" "PicName" and "Storage", as seen below:

Batch File:

```
        set Pathname="C:\User\username\locationOfFile 
        cd /d %Pathname%
        cscript.exe C:\User\username\locationOfFile\myScript.vbs IPADDRESS PicName Storage
```

In my VB6 program, the parameter values are defined.

Lets say for instance IPADDRESS = "170.190.xxx.xxx"

Is there a way I can have the batch file read and use the value of IPADDRESS based off the declaration inside the VB6 form?  The variables IPADDRESS, PicName, and Storage will be constantly changing based off an outside application the VB6 program talks to so I cant statically set it up in the batch (  ....\myScript.vbs 170.190.xxx.xxx pic1 C:\Storage)

My VBScript is given below:

```
   Option explicit

   if WScript.Arguments.Count <> 3 then
      WScript.Echo "Missing parameters"
   else

   Dim imageMagick
   Set imageMagick = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")

   Dim cam_add 
   Dim annotate 
   Dim filename 
   Dim cmd
   Dim WshShell
   Dim return

   cam_add = """http://" & WScript.Arguments(0) &"/image"""
   annotate = """" & WScript.Arguments(1) & " - """ '& Date
   filename = """" & WScript.Arguments(2) & WScript.Arguments(1) & ".jpg"""
   cmd = "convert " & cam_add & " -fill gold -pointsize 45 -gravity southwest -annotate         0x0+25+25 " & annotate & " -trim +repage -verbose " & filename

   WScript.Echo cmd

   Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   WshShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\"

   return = WshShell.Run(cmd) 


   end if
```

In summation, I need to to have the batch set up like:

cscript.exe C:\User\username\locationOfFile\myScript.vbs IPADDRESS PicName Storage

so the parameter values can used according to what they are set to inside my VB6 form.

Comment: It looks like you are already passing in the three variables into your script via cmd line args.  What error are you seeing when you shell to this script via your VB6 app?

Comment: I'm not getting errors per say, however I have to statically code the parameter values instead using a variable name in the batch file. For example I have to type out an exact IP address value rather than use IPADDRESS, or code an exact storage location (C:\MyStorage\) rather than just use STORAGE. The VB6 form will determine the values for me, I just need the batch file to essentially copy and use the values given in the Vb6 program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something this simple there is no need for a batch file anyway.  After all, you have a *whole script* to work with.

You can even set the CD from inside there, or set it in the VB6 program as here:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Main()
    Dim CD As String
    Dim IPADDRESS  As String
    Dim PicName As String
    Dim Storage As String
    Dim OrigCD As String

    CD = "D:\Photo Archives"
    IPADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
    PicName = "Fudd"
    Storage = "C:\Storage"

    'Cache CD so we can restore it.
    'Change CD and drive so it is inherited.
    OrigCD = CurDir$()
    ChDir CD
    ChDrive CD

    Shell "cscript """ _
        & App.Path & "\test.vbs "" """ _
        & IPADDRESS & """ """ _
        & PicName & """ """ _
        & Storage & """", _
          vbNormalFocus

    'Restore CD and drive.
    ChDir OrigCD
    ChDrive OrigCD

    'Rest of program.
End Sub
```

Script sample:

```
Option Explicit

Private CD

Private Sub Msg(ByVal Text)
    With WScript
        .StdOut.WriteLine Text
        .StdOut.Write "Press ENTER to continue..."
        .StdIn.ReadLine
    End With
End Sub

If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 3 Then
    Msg "Missing parameters"
    WScript.Quit
End If

'Show the CD and the arguments.
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    CD = .CurrentDirectory
End With
With WScript.Arguments
    Msg CD & vbNewLine _
      & """" & .Item(0) _
      & """ """ & .Item(1) _
      & """ """ & .Item(2) & """"
End With
```

But it doesn't even look like the script is needed.  You can build the command, set the CD/drive, and Shell() the built command string all from inside the VB6 program.

Comment: Wow that was extremely helpful. I just ran it out of the VB6 project as you suggested and it worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you were to:

```
shell "the.bat " & IPADDRESS & " " & PicName & " " & Storage
```

then within `the.bat` each space delimited argument is available via `%N` where `N` is the ordinal number; so `%1` would contain the value of `IPADDRESS`, `%2` would contain `PicName`'s value and so on.

To then forward to the VBScript:

```
cscript.exe C:\User\username\locationOfFile\myScript.vbs %1 %2 %3
```

(If any of the variables contain spaces, you will need to "quote" them before passing to the bat file)

(You could also probably just `chdir(..)` in VB6 then run CScript directly)

Comment: Oh ok! So do I need to anything with the batch file so it knows to expect variables or just simply add the %1 %2 %3?

Comment: Just use them, you don't need to do anything special; http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true